# How to safely store PBEKeySpec password?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, keystore

I have following method to derive cryptographic key:

```
private static SecretKey deriveKeySecurely(byte[] salt){
    String password = "FAKE_PASSWORD";
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, sITERATION_COUNT, sKEY_SIZE_IN_BYTES * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory;
    try {
        keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(sALGORITHM);
        byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, sSECRET_KEY_ALGORTHM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            Log.e(sLOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this example password String is hardcoded. I know I could use SharedPreferences to store this password but I´m not sure its the secure way to do that. Could be Android KeyStore somehow useful here?

Comment: Yes, that's what the key store is for.